# How do I access the properties of my object using STAssertTrue

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, unit-testing

How do I access the properties of my object using STAssertTrue in unit tests?

I don't have access to the properties of my object and I want to do a comparison?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access object properties as usual, so I guess you are talking about missing code completion... I think is an xcode bug, if you want code completion, you have to type before a call to STAssertTrue() (or any others OCUnit macro), like:

```
NSString *foo = [myObject fooString];
STAssertTrue([foo length] > 1, nil);
```